# Adding Line Breaks to an HTTPresponseMessage Web API C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am going to start off and say please be patient with me as I am learning C# and I will do my best to be specific.

We use a third party instant messenger in house. They added the ability to do slash commands within the messenger to get certain information. Their only out of the box option is "/weather " gives you the current weather for that zip code.

I would like to use it internally to provide information to my users thats is contained in our SQL Server. My proof of concept project is pulling active discounts using /discounts and from that output you can type /disocunts  to list items available in that discount.

I have the web api created in Visual Studio and for the most part its working as I would like it to. I need to add some error reporting but other than that it works pretty good. My biggest problem is the output that the user sees.

Currently with my webAPI I am geting this format back into the messenger:

["8 - VAPE LIQUID - 2 for $2.00","11 - WILDBERRY INCENSE 1","15 - PREMIUM CIGAR DISCOUNT - BUNDLE","16 - PREMIUM CIGAR DISCOUNT"]

I would like for their to be a line break at least where every "," Ideally the output would be:

"8 - VAPE LIQUID - 2 for $2.00"

"11 - WILDBERRY INCENSE 1"

"15 - PREMIUM CIGAR DISCOUNT - BUNDLE"

"16 - PREMIUM CIGAR DISCOUNT"

Here is the code from my API Contoller.

```
public class DiscountsController : ApiController
{
    private DiscountsEntities db = new DiscountsEntities();

    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Authenticate(FormDataCollection form)
    {
        var message = form.Get("Message");

        if (message == "/discounts" )
        {

           var ReturnedDiscounts = from d in db.Discounts
                                    where d.DiscountStartDate < DateTime.Now && d.DiscountStopDate >= DateTime.Now
                                    orderby d.DiscountPriority ascending
                                    select string.Concat(d.DiscountPriority, " - ", d.DiscountName);

            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,ReturnedDiscounts);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain");


            return response;
```

Any help or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Replace it? `ReturnedDiscounts.Replace("\",", "\"" + Environment.NewLine)`- if this is going to end up being rendered as html replace with `<br/>` instead.

Comment: @AlexK. `ReturnedDiscounts` is an enumerable - WebAPI is formatting it into a comma separated list. EDIT: actually it is being formatted into a JSON array

Comment: I tried to use the replace before with the variable ReturnedDiscounts, but it kept returning the actual linq query and not the results. When it did show the query there were not any line breaks it just showed /r/n in the middle of the query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to return an object in the message. You can just return a string....

```
var strResponse = string.Join("\n", ReturnedDiscounts);

HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, strResponse);
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain");

return response;
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you are using WebAPI 2 you can do this to make sure it does not have quotes as well - which is probably more desirable

```
var strResponse = string.Join("\n", ReturnedDiscounts);

return Content(strResponse);
```

If that doesn't work you can also do...

```
return new HttpResponseMessage()
{
    Content = new StringContent(strResponse, Encoding.UTF8, "text/html")
};
```

Comment: It doesnt appear to like the Join



Error CS1501 No overload for method 'Join' takes 1 arguments DiscountProject

Comment: @BobbyDigital wrogn Join. use `string.Join("\n", ReturnedDiscounts)`

Comment: Thanks Nkosi that corrected that. I ended up having to use the <br/> as suggested above. it was putting the actual characters \n throught the string in the result.